# Bug ao filtrar exibição de Perguntas

Tags: bug, status-recusado

Estava navegando pelas formas de filtrar perguntas, e acredito que encontrei um Bug:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As URLs acessadas foram, nesta ordem:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+multithreading+thread+orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos+classes+android
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java+multithreading+thread+orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos+classes+android&sort=newest

Veja que primeiro eu estou em "Perguntas não Respondidas" na aba "Minhas Tags", e há várias Perguntas na lista. Depois, eu clico no botão "todas as perguntas" e ao invés de aparecerem mais perguntas (todas elas) não aparece mais nenhuma! E o texto "Perguntas não Respondidas" muda para "Perguntas da tag", além de que a aba "minhas tags" desaparece e a aba "recentes" passa a ser a aba aberta.

Pra mim todo esse comportamento não faz sentido. Eu esperava que, a presença do botão "todas as perguntas" na primeira página acessada significasse que eu não estou exibindo todas elas (há perguntas filtradas) e que eu posso clicar nesse botão para exibí-las (ou seja, parar de filtrar para "exibir todas"), mas ao clicar nele todas as perguntas desaparecem.

Ao clicar no botão também aparecem uma série de Tags na minha barra de pesquisa, afinal o que isso significa? que eu estou tentando exibir todas as perguntas que possuem todas aquelas tags? Se é isso o botão deveria se chamar algo como "filtrar perguntas pelas tags" ou outra coisa assim.

Por fim, temos aquele link para o feed, ele deveria mesmo estar lá? ele parece desalinhado no layout; e não vi um link de feed aparecer nas outras listas de perguntas (nem no começo nem no final).

Comment: Qual seria o bug?

Comment: @UzmkArtanis Não tem nenhum código sendo mostrado, isso é _feed_ RSS.

Comment: @UzmkArtanis Também não é **estranho** o sistema pesquisar por todas estas tags. Perceba na url **?tab=myTags**, ou seja, todas as perguntas das suas tags favoritas.

Comment: Então, jovem. Essas são as suas tags...

Comment: No momento que vc clica em **todas as perguntas** o sistema faz a busca de perguntas que contenham todas as tags da busca (no caso, as suas tags).

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque o comportamento indicado é o esperado

Answer (score 7):

**Isto não é um BUG**, é teu navegador que não tem leitor de Feeds nativo. Os [feeds](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feed) ([RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) / [ATOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard))) são um meio de ficar atualizado sem precisar navegar nos sites, existem vários clientes de feeds que integram com o navegador.

Note também que você clicou em um link que tem um icone do RSS que é parecido com isto:

[image: feed]

Veja, isto indica que é justamente usado para leitores de Feed:

> [image: feed link]

### Como funcionam os Feeds

Os Feeds são algo muito útil ao meu ver, quase todas páginas do Stack Overflow usam, então você pode escolher o que deseja acompanhar, salvando o feed no teu "cliente", aqui no site você pode acompanhar:

- Uma ou mais perguntas especificas
- Tags por tipo de ordenação
- Novas perguntas ou respostas

### Clientes de Feed

- [Chrome extesão RSS Feed Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-feed-reader/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp)
- O Opera tem um cliente nativo, mas você pode usar algo mais tradicional instalado os add-ons [Smart feed](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/smart-rss/?display=en) que precisa usar combinado com [RSS Detector](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/rss-detector/?display=en) (ou pode simplesmente copiar a URL)
- Firefox já tem detector de feeds nativos e podem ser adicionados a barras de favoritos (ou a um "cliente web"):

  [image: firefox]

### Clientes web

- https://www.inoreader.com
- https://theoldreader.com

Comment: Esta resposta dava para site principal :D